# upload text files to server through html and then reading on server

Tags: html, file, jsp, upload

I can already upload files and then read them on the server, I just have a problem with the extra data at the beginning of the input stream. My code in jsp:

```
      <%     
  DataInputStream   dis = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
  String strLine;
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
  out.println (strLine+"");
  }
%>
```

I get this data at the beginning that I would like to skip 
-----------------------------41184676334 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="data.txt" Content-Type: text/plain 
and also this at the end
 -----------------------------41184676334--

I would to make an universal solution for this for any text file.

Comment: Does your form have the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: I have zero knowledge of JSP, but [this article](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/file_upload/Sinle_upload.xhtml.shtml) makes it look like accessing the file is far more complex than your code. Hope it gives you some ideas